# How do I use a user input as a function parameter?

Tags: c++

I have a function `void mainRoutine(string searchStrings, string fileBeingSearched, char K, char B);`

I want the parameters in my mainRoutine function, searchStrings and fileBeingSearched to be the name of the file that the user types in. (example - I type in "b.txt", that is the string that searchStrings should take in.).

So after I prompt the user to enter the filename:

```
string userInput;
cout << "Please enter the string file to be searched: " << endl;
getline(cin, userInput);
ifstream filename(userInput.c_str());
while(filename.good()&&filename.peek()!=EOF)
{
        cout << (char)filename.get();
}
cout << "\n";

string userInput2;
cout << "Please enter the file to be searched: " << endl;
getline(cin, userInput2);
ifstream fileToBeSearched(userInput.c_str());
while(fileToBeSearched.good()&&fileToBeSearched.peek()!=EOF){
        cout << (char)fileToBeSearched.get();
}
cout << "\n";
```

How do I connect it so that the userInput is the string of the function parameter?

Comment: Try `mainRoutine(userInput, userInput2, 'K', 'B');`

Answer (score 1):

```
mainRoutine(userInput, userInput2, K, B);
```

Supposed that K and B are **char** type